# rename files based on source file

Tags: shell, for-loop, awk, while-loop

I have 224 pdf files and I'd like to prefix the files with a number and _

Example: 
stackoverflow_nov_2014.pdf

File accounts.csv contains:
2567,stackoverflow

So the goal is to take 2567 and prefix it to the pdf file with an underscore:
2567_stackoverflow_nov_2014.pdf

I think I would want to use read -r in a while loop as explained here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147569/rename-a-batch-of-files-after-reading-from-a-source-file

But when attempting this as it's written, the shell gives usage of mv command and nothing changes with the files.

Edit: Adding sample data from sources file (accounts.csv)

```
11,My_Golf_Shop
2567,stackoverflow    
11122,Test_Store
```

By the way, the sources file (accounts.csv) isn't in the same order as the files in the directory as accounts.csv so somehow there would need to be matching with file name and the accounts.csv that occurs.

Comment: Would you show your shell script here to clarify?

Comment: Hi Jackie, other than what's posted in the link above, I don't have a script. I'll post some data from the sources file, though.

Comment: Have you noticed that in the stackexchange link examples, the file containing the file names to rename are made of lines whose field separator is the `blank space` and in your case the field separator is the comma `;`?

Comment: Hi @Jdamian `mv $(awk -F, '{print $1}' <<$line)` results in the same result: usage on mv. 
The link may not be applicable for my situation, either.

Comment: Yes, `mv $(awk -F, '{print $1}' <<$line)` fails because ***only ONE argument*** is found by the `mv` command and it needs ***TWO arguments*** at least. To debug, use `echo mv $(awk -F, '{print $1}' <<$line)` and you will see something like `mv file1` and compare to `echo mv $(awk -F, '{print $1" "$2}' <<$line)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the script that should work under the assumption:
1. All the files are under the same folder
2. For a particular prefix, this script will only rename the first found file.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    num=`echo $line |cut -f 1 -d ","`
    prefix=`echo $line |cut -f 2 -d ","`
    if [ -n "$num" -a -n "$prefix" ]; then
        full_file=$(basename `eval find . -name '$prefix\*' -print -quit` 2>/dev/null ) 
        mv $full_file ${num}_$full_file 2>/dev/null
    fi
done < accounts.csv
```

Comment: Instead of using cut to parse the line, just set IFS: `while IFS=, read -r num prefix; do ...`

Comment: Jackie's worked great! There were about 20 that were not renamed but that's not a fault of the script.

Comment: Hello @WilliamPursell, Which cut do you suggest replacing?

Comment: Both of them.  Try `while IFS=, read -r num prefix; do echo num=$num prefix=$prefix; done < accounts.csv`

Comment: William's suggestion is great! Thank you!